# Displaying someting in email template based on a Date value

Tags: email, email-template

I am using a visual force template and want to add some logic which will decide whether to display something based on a date field in an Opportunity being less than a certain value.

I try:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.opportunity__r.LastModifiedDate > System.now() - 30, true, false)}">Stalled</apex:outputpanel>
```

I get:  Error: Unknown function System.now. Check spelling

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is replace **System.now()** with **NOW()**.

Comment: does NOW() - 2 mean minus days or 2 minutes?

Comment: @dublintech You can print those on page or inspect through javascript alert to find

Comment: @dublintech it will be minus 2 days